# Why IntegerValidator from Apache Commons fails with this number

Tags: java, macos

I'm using the [Apache Commons Validator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) library to validate an integer. With this code:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    System.out.println("Validate 0.1: " + IntegerValidator.getInstance().isValid("0.1"));
    }
}
```

This code returns true, I don't know why. 0.1, at least for me, is not an integer. Also my locale is es_ES.UTF-8 and I'm running this code in an MacOS X 10.10 ...

But, under Linux (with locale en_US.UTF-8) works fine:

```
terron@ubuntuelastic:~/checkApacheCommon/target$ java -classpath checkApacheCommon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:commons-validator-1.4.0.jar  org.ctb.maven.App
Validate 0.1: false
```

Is there any bug in the library or in OS X related to this system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In es_ES locale (Spanish), dot "." is a thousands separator, not a decimal point. So 0.1 is interpreted as 1. One tenth would be written with a decimal comma: 0,1.

In your second example you're using en_US locale, where dot is indeed a decimal point.

Comment: Yes. I have installed the es_ES locale in my Linux box and now I have the same results as Mac OS X. I suspected the problem was the locale, but in Spain usually we also use the dot as  the decimal point.